# Figura vs Imagem

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro

Existem diferenças entre "figura" e "imagem"?

Em um texto acadêmico, eu posso usar os dois ou algum é preferido a outro?

Comment: Uma busca rápida no priberam resolveria essa pergunta para os dois substantivos. Ademais, figura pode ser conjugação do verbo figurar.

Comment: Acho que é  preciso mostrar o que você encontrou ou pensa sobre o assunto primeiro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - [**figura**](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/figura) - entre as diversas definições encontradas no Priberam, a que mais se aplica a um texto acadêmico é "desenho ilustrativo de um texto"
> - [**imagem**](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/imagem) - "representação de pessoa ou coisa"

Em um texto científico, figura é o termo genérico para qualquer ilustração.  A figura pode ser um gráfico, uma tabela, uma foto, um desenho, uma pintura e até mesmo uma imagem.

Exemplos:

> - A figura 25 mostra o aspecto histológico do material colhido.
> - A figura a seguir mostra o protocolo adotado para o ensaio clínico.
> - Na figura 27 podemos ver a imagem angiográfica da região afetada.
> - O desenho da figura 12 representa o provável aspecto após a remoção do tumor.

Imagem é um termo mais específico, podendo ser uma fotografia, cópia ou desenho de coisa. (radiográficas, tomográficas, de ressonância magnética, de ultrassonografia, etc.) podemos listá-las com números: a imagem nº1 mostra..., na imagem nº7 vemos...

Já no contexto de ótica geométrica, "imagem" tem um [significado técnico bastante preciso](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%93tica_geom%C3%A9trica).

Comment: Centaurus, como físico, o conceito ótico de imagem é o primeiro que me vem à mente. :) Mas, por favor, fique à vontade para alterar ou desfazer minha edição, se julgar a adição desnecessária.

Comment: @stafusa  Welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Em trabalhos academico utilize figura quando utilizar   desenhos e imagem quando estiver relacionado a fotografias.

Comment: ou melhor, quando inserir no trabalho fotografias mencione imagem e quando for utilizado desenhos ou  gravura citará figura.

Answer (score 1):

São palavras com usos semelhantes, mas não idênticos:

> O Cavaleiro da Triste Figura (mas não o Cavaleiro da Triste Imagem).
>
> A imagem do meu televisor está péssima (mas não a figura do meu
>   televisor).
>
> Se você quer ser eleito, precisa trabalhar a sua imagem (mas não a sua
>   figura).
>
> A figura nº 15 (e não a imagem nº 15).
>
> O Jacó é uma figura (mas não uma imagem).

No contexto que você implica (trabalhos acadêmicos) você provavelmente está pensando se deve ter um índice de figuras ou de imagens. No caso, são figuras, não imagens. Mas mesmo num trabalho acadêmico, haverá situações em que você estará lidando com imagens, ou com coisas que podem ser figuras ou imagens.

Comment: São exemplos do uso idiomático das duas palavras.  Lembro ainda de "a imagem de N.S. de Fátima" (mas não a figura).